# Excel formula - How to separate a formula value in a cell into 2 different cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my Excel sheet I have a column which gets the transposed data from a row of a different sheet.

```
=TRANSPOSE(DATA!L170:CC170)
```

An example of a cell's data is `0/300` and is consistent throughout the column.

Now I plan to have 2 new columns next to the first column to show the numbers separate:

```
| 0/300 | 0 | 300 |
```

I want the 2 columns to show their values as soon as there is data on the first column.

At first I wanted to try out the built in text to column function. But apparently it doesn't work because it only detects the formula and not the value.

Is there any other formula that can do what I want? A macro would certainly work but I'm also looking for a more simpler method if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods you could try:

**Method 1**

**Formula for Column A:**

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1),"")
```

**Formula for Column B:**

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"")
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Method 2**

- Select your Data
- Go to Data
- Data Tools tab
- Text to Columns
- Delimited - Next
- Other: import  "/" in the box - Next
- Finish

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Just realized that this formula doesn't work for Excel 2003. Is there another formula I can use for that?

Comment: what problem do you get?

Comment: #VALUE! is what I have for the data.

Comment: Do you get the same result with other excel versions?

Comment: I only have 2010 (what I'm using to develop) and 2003 (user who is using file) accessible right now.

Comment: so in 2010 it works and in 2003 doesnt? in 2016 & 2019 works perfectly.

Comment: Is it possible that the formula is not supported in 2003?

Comment: So looking up online, I found out that 'IFERROR` is not compatible with Excel 2003. The workaround I ended up using: 1) `=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(I1,FIND("/",I1)-1)),"", (LEFT(I1,FIND("/",I1)-1)))` for the left number 2) `=IF(ISERROR(MID(I1,FIND("/",I1)+1,LEN(I1)-FIND("/",I1))), "", (MID(I1,FIND("/",I1)+1,LEN(I1)-FIND("/",I1))))` for the right number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191587/discussion-between-error-1004-and-hjh93).

Answer (score 3):

That might be quite difficult to achieve. I guess, impossible.

Why? Because the **TRANSPOSE** function returns a range of a very exact size, without room to add new columns inside.

Workaround:

Add the extra-columns at the right, beyond the end of the range. Just use the **LEFT** / **MID** / **RIGHT** functions to get the fragments from the original text.

The workaround will work if the size of the range does not change, and if the contents are always the same in the same positions. If you want a (highly) adaptive formula, you will need to go into VBA for Excel, and that's going to be "uglier".

---

Edit: I took it for granted, but **@MitchellDeane** has a good point:

> Note that you can use **FIND** in your left functions in case of different sizes of inputs: =LEFT(A1,(FIND("/",A1,1)-1)). Such as 0/300, 0/3000, 30/30000

Comment: Note that you can use FIND in your left functions in case of different sizes of inputs: =LEFT(A1,(FIND("/",A1,1)-1)). Such as 0/300, 0/3000, 30/30000